# Repartition Dell XPS13 with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: partitioning

I bought a Dell XPS13 with Ubuntu 12.04 pre-installed. I want to reformat and repartition the machine, but as I'm far from being a Linux guru.  I'm afraid that I'll erase something important that could have been preinstalled by Dell.

On the disk, there are 3 partitions:

- `/dev/sda1` - Ext4 Linux bootable 248GB - which is the system+user partition, I guess.
- `/dev/sda2` - Extended (?) of 8GB - What is this partition about?
- `/dev/sda5` - Linux Swap of 8GB - which is for RAM and needs to be reconduct (why only 1xRAM and not 2?)

Do I have to care about `/dev/sda2`?
Can I reformat to create a partition for `/home` without losing anything important (except user data of course)?

Answer (score 1):

That is the standard Ubuntu partition Layout, there is no hidden restore partition like you can get with Windows systems.
You are safe to repartition **after backing your data up.**

You can easily create root, home and swap partitions from the Ubuntu installer, just selected the advanced options, official help:

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/amd64/module-details.html#di-partition

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to keep any pre-existing dell partition if you're not using windows, so feel free to use the entire disk.